# Telegram bot (pyTelegramBotAPI) does not handle new user joining group

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I have recently created a simple bot for telegram using the pyTelegramBotAPI (telebot).
I added a message handler that is supposed to handle **every** message, including the ones that appear on a group when a new user joins, which are still `Message` objects a non-null `new_chat_members` property.

```py
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

[...]

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def foo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"I got the message")



bot.polling()
```

Even so, the bot does not reply with the "I got the message" string when I add a new user, although it does catch other messages.

Why is this happening? Is this a problem about the message handler? Is there maybe a more general handler that is sure to catch every update?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should specify "`new_chat_members`" as `content-types`.

Here is a sample working snippet that welcomes new users:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=[
    "new_chat_members"
])
def foo(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "welcome")

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Thanks. I still wonder why it handles those messages if you specify that filter, but it doesn't when you ask him to handle everything.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that `content_types` is by default `['text']` (according to the docs.). So you have to specify all the `content-types` you want to capture yourself if you wish to capture multiple update types in the same handler.

Comment: So even if you specify `bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)`. There is still an implicit `content-types` restriction that scopes it to only text messages.